# unity c# check color of sprite OnCollisionEnter2d()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have been trying to check the color of the sprite on collision. If the colors are the same then then nothing happens but if they are different one of them should get destroyed.

This is how I change the color of a sprite:

```
Color newColor = new Color(0.68f, 0.88f, 0.33f);
                    m_spriteRenderer.color = newColor;
```

And this is my OnColl. Method until now:

```
  public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

    }
```

Comment: `one of them should get destroyed` .. which one? And could you add the code of what you tried so far? Currently no color is checked at all ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do as the following

```cs
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color != m_spriteRenderer.color)
        Destroy(gameObject); // Note1
}
```

**Note1** : You said `one of them should get destroyed`, so you can do

```cs
Destroy(collision.gameObject);
```

depends of what you need.

---

Dont forget to add a collider to both your **GameObject**s. A BoxCollider2D may be enough.

Comment: If both objects register the `OnCollisionEnter2D` call then `Destroy(collision.gameObject);` will destroy both of them though ;)

Comment: That is true. I will edit the answer if the case appears, depends of what he needs exactly.